# What's the impact of studying learning theory in actual learning?

Tags: learning

Are there any studies showing the impacts of learning about learning theory on someone's learning?
Moreover, at which point learning about learning first makes an impact on you learning a new subject? (eg: learning about learning+then studying the new subject becomes better than simple studying the subject, both time-wise and depth-of-understanding-wise).